# How to understand Multitenancy is enabled or not in view?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

We are not using multi-tenancy. When it is disabled most of the tenant related UI gets hidden but in the LinkedAccount page, the user can view the tenancy name(which is Default). We wanted to hide it in the UI. Tried to find a property like `IsMultiTenancyEnabled` but couldn't find(Actually it is in the `IMultiTenancyConfig` but not available to razor page). So, how can hide UI elements if Multitenancy is not enabled?

```
//This is the code we want to hide. 
<div class="form-group">
        <label>@L("TenancyName")</label>
        <input type="text" name="TenancyName" class="form-control" value="@(ViewBag.TenancyName ?? "")" maxlength="@TurkKizilayi.RFL.MultiTenancy.Tenant.MaxTenancyNameLength">
</div>
```

And there is one thing more: What happens if we hide this code anyway? Should we change the model or app service (Yes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MVC you can inject IMultiTenancyConfig into your view.
Here is the final code of what you want;

```
@inject IMultiTenancyConfig MultiTenancyConfig
@using Abp.Configuration.Startup
@using MyCompanyName.AbpZeroTemplate.Web.Areas.AppAreaName.Models.Common.Modals
@Html.Partial("~/Areas/AppAreaName/Views/Common/Modals/_ModalHeader.cshtml", new ModalHeaderViewModel(L("LinkNewAccount")))

<div class="modal-body">
    <form name="LinkAccountModalForm" role="form" novalidate class="form-validation">

        @if (MultiTenancyConfig.IsEnabled)
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>@L("TenancyName")</label>
                <input type="text" name="TenancyName" class="form-control" value="@(ViewBag.TenancyName ?? "")" maxlength="@MyCompanyName.AbpZeroTemplate.MultiTenancy.Tenant.MaxTenancyNameLength">
            </div>
        }

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>@L("UserName")</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="UsernameOrEmailAddress" required maxlength="@MyCompanyName.AbpZeroTemplate.Authorization.Users.User.MaxEmailAddressLength">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>@L("Password")</label>
            <input type="password" name="Password" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" required maxlength="@MyCompanyName.AbpZeroTemplate.Authorization.Users.User.MaxPasswordLength">
        </div>
    </form>

</div>

@Html.Partial("~/Areas/AppAreaName/Views/Common/Modals/_ModalFooterWithSaveAndCancel.cshtml")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already a service `AbpMultiTenancyService` in the Angular project. `AppComponentBase` already has definition for `multiTenancy`. so if your component class is inheriting from `AppComponentBase` then you can directly use this service.

You can define a property in `*.ts` file like below.

```
isMultiTenancyEnabled: boolean = this.multiTenancy.isEnabled
```

Then you can use the same in HTML like below.

```
*ngIf="isMultiTenancyEnabled"
```

Or you can simply use the following code.

```
abp.multiTenancy.isEnabled
```

Comment: Thanks, this may valid for angular project but we are using Core2.0 Jquery project

Comment: You don’t have ‘abp.multiTenancy’ in your project?

Comment: If you mean: write javascript code and manipulate DOM if `ab.multiTenancy.isEnabled = false`. Yea it may be true but I was looking for a razor code. Looks like we need to check it in the controller and send `isEnabled` value with `ViewBag` like in the default code. Thanks.